# PHP regex for pattern, but not preceeded by some string

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP app that needs to parse a comma separated list of items in any order. Unfortunately some of the keywords overlap:

```
$mylist = 'foo,wind,unwind';

$contains_foo = preg_match('/foo/i', $mylist);
$contains_bar = preg_match('/bar/i', $mylist);
$contains_unwind = preg_match('/unwind/i', $mylist);
$contains_wind = preg_match('/wind/i', $mylist); # BUG!
```

How can I craft a regex that only matches 'wind' if its not preceeded by 'un' ?

Note that I can't match for `/,wind/`, because it might be the first item in the list.

I could probably do `/^wind/ || /,wind/` but would prefer to have it in a single regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I craft a regex that only matches 'wind' if its not preceeded by 'un' ?

You can use a **negative lookbehind**:

```
$contains_wind = preg_match('/(?<!un)wind/i', $mylist);
```

Here `(?<!un)` is a *negative lookbehind* which means fail the match if word `wind` is preceded by `un`.

---

On another note looking at your example you could also use **word boundaries**:

```
$contains_wind = preg_match('/\bwind\b/i', $mylist);
```

Here assertion `\b` is called *word boundary* that will match `wind` only if it is surrounded by non-word characters or anchors.